# Laradock migrate command No Such File or Directory

Tags: php, laravel, docker-compose, laravel-artisan

When i enter my workspace and write command `php artisan migrate` it gives me this error:

```
php artisan migrate

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = deneme and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:678
    674▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    675▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    676▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    677▕         catch (Exception $e) {
  ➜ 678▕             throw new QueryException(
    679▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    680▕             );
    681▕         }
    682▕

      +33 vendor frames
  34  artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
```

I recently Dockerized my local project and configured it with docker but it doesn't work. Any help?

Comment: You need to update .env, set database host to service name of MySQL in your docker-composer.yml

Comment: Where exactly i find it in docker-compose.yml?

Comment: check your project root

Comment: I know where it is located but can't find anything related to 'database host service' in docker-compose.yml.

Comment: try `DB_HOST=mysql` in .env

Comment: Already did. Is it a problem that i don't have docker-compose-yml in my project folder? Cause i use laradock and there is already a docker-compose.yml file there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228050/discussion-between-emeka-mbah-and-yarkinbey).